# can't import python extension

Tags: python, windows, python-c-extension

I'm trying to learn python extensions, and I created the simple [noddy example](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html) c file and setup.py.

`python.exe setup.py build`  gives me:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'noddy' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win32-2.7
creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\python27\include -IC:\python27\PC /Tcnoddy.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\noddy.obj
noddy.c
creating build\lib.win32-2.7
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\python27\PCbuild /EXPORT:initnoddy build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\noddy.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\noddy.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\noddy.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\noddy.pyd.manifest
Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\noddy.lib and object build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\noddy.exp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\mt.exe -nologo -manifest build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\noddy.pyd.manifest -outputresource:build\lib.win32-2.7\noddy.pyd;2
```

I then run `python.exe setup.py install`, which gives me:

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
running install_lib
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\noddy.pyd -> C:\python27\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\noddy-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

But then, in Idle,

```
>>> import noddy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import noddy
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So, what am I doing wrong?  Admittedly, I am horribly confused.

Comment: Possibly a dumb question but are you sure you're using Python 2.7 when you are trying to `import` it?

Comment: It was a clean 2.7 install on a machine that had never had python on it before.  Is there a method to call from Idle that gives the version?

Comment: To get the python version: `import sys; sys.version_info`. Can you post your setup.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio 2008 compiler to build the module.

VS8 is Visual Studio 2005 and the modules compiled with that version are incompatible with Python 2.7 (same applies to modules compiled with Visual Studio 2010 btw.).

Comment: If that is my problem, is there a place to find Python 2.7 built for VS 2005, as that's what my company works on?  I am happy to learn using a different setup, but I don't think they would want to incorporate it into their build system.

Comment: It worked, but it's a shame that no one does a distribution of Python 2.7 built with VS 2005... I don't think my boss will want to deal with VS2008.

Comment: Look which year we have now. VS2005 is outdated. Besides that, you really don't want that. All python modules which contain binary packages wouldn't work with the VS2005 python and you'd have to compile them manually.